# How can I extract comments from all the links in a website Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract comments from few forums from the website. I have list of links from which I want the comments to be extracted. When I give single link instead of {i} in the code (f"{i}/index{item}/")) the code works fine, but with the below code it is giving an empty list.

data

```
    name                    Link
    a               https://www.f150forum.com/f118/2019-adding-ada...
    b               https://www.f150forum.com/f118/2018-adding-ada...
    c               https://www.f150forum.com/f118/adaptive-cruise...
    d               https://www.f150forum.com/f118/2018-platinum-s...
    e               https://www.f150forum.com/f118/adaptive-cruise...
    f               https://www.f150forum.com/f118/adaptive-cruise...
```

My code

```
link_url = []
username=[]
comments = []

for i in df['Link']:
    with requests.Session() as req:
        for item in range(1):
            r = req.get(
            f"{i}/index{item}/")
            soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
            link_url.append(item)
            for item in soup.findAll('div',attrs={"class":"ism-true"}):
                result = [item.get_text(strip=True, separator=" ")]
                comments.append(result)
            for item in soup.findAll('a',attrs={"class":"bigusername"}):
                name = [item.get_text(strip=True, separator=" ")]
                username.append(name)
```

Can you please help me with this. Thank you in advance.

Comment: did you try to print the formatted address and see if it comes out the way you expect it to?

Comment: Link is showing as a dtype object. How can I convert that to a link.

Comment: What do you get if you do `print(i)` inside the for loop?

Comment: I am getting each individual lists and when I copy the link it's taking me to correct website.

Answer (score 0):

OK , I see your links are in a dataframe, you can loop them with :

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

data = """
name,Link
a,https://www.f150forum.com/f118/2019-adding-ada...
b,https://www.f150forum.com/f118/2018-adding-ada...
c,https://www.f150forum.com/f118/adaptive-cruise...
d,https://www.f150forum.com/f118/2018-platinum-s...
e,https://www.f150forum.com/f118/adaptive-cruise...
"""
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data),sep=',')
for index, row in df.iterrows():
  print(row['Link'])
```

result :

```
https://www.f150forum.com/f118/2019-adding-ada...
https://www.f150forum.com/f118/2018-adding-ada...
https://www.f150forum.com/f118/adaptive-cruise...
https://www.f150forum.com/f118/2018-platinum-s...
https://www.f150forum.com/f118/adaptive-cruise...
```

then , put the value(link) inside of your requests

Comment: When I am doing that and printing item It shows that it is not extracting any links

Comment: @anonymous13  how is your dataframe exactly??

Comment: My Data frame is just 2 columns and is a subset of other data frame, both the columns are string. It is exactly like in the question, and the above code is reading the link "https://www.f150forum.com/clientscript/gcs/gcs.css?v=393813"